# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized, while running Database-Update Command

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, connection-string, entity-framework-migrations

I am getting this error while running the "Update-Database" command in Package Manager Console. I am working on a project with Three Tier Structure. In which I have Three Projects other than MVC COre API.

1. Project.Model
2. Project.Repository
3. Project.Service

My DB-Context is in Repository and the `connectionstring` is in the "appsetting.json" file, and I am using the Dependency Injection in "program.cs" file to provide the `connectionstring`. But when ever I run the command it shows the error:

> "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized".

When I hardcode `Connectionstring` to "Database" property of `DbContext` class in my `AppDBContext` constructor. It's working fine.
But HardCoding is not a good approach. So I Tried to make a new static class having property `connectionstrings` and assign the property in "program.cs" and access the property in `AppDBContext` constructor to set the `connectionstring` to database. Then I get another error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I make a static class in my Repository Project named as `ConfigurationManage` and a Dictionary Property `ConnectionStrings`:

```
public static class ConfigurationManager { public static Dictionary<string,string> ConnectionStrings { get; set; }; }
```

Then I assign the Connectionstring in "Program.cs" class.

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").Get<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

and finally access the object in "AppDBContext" Constructor.

```
public AppDBContext(DbContextOptions<AppDBContext> options) : base(options)
{  
    Database.SetConnectionString( ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"]); 
}
```

Comment: There are a *lot* of duplicate questions and the answer is provided in the EF Core Migrations documentation - the tool needs to know where to find the connection, and that "where" is the .NET configuration subsystem. By trying to put another abstraction over the configuration abstraction, the tools can't find the connection any longer. In fact, this code *introduces* hard-coding by discarding the connection string supplied in `options` and replacing it with the hard-coded one in `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`

Comment: The short version is, remove all the customizations, use EF Core, DbContext as the samples show. In the samples the DbContext itself doesn't know where the connection string is coming from, allowing you to even use different connections with the same DbContext

Comment: The line `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings = builder.Configuration.GetSection` is another hard-coding bug. This looks like an attempt to re-introduce .NET Framework's ConnectionManager, a class that made N-Tier a lot harder by hard-coding configuration access to `web.config`. This was fixed by providing the provider-agnostic IConfiguration in .NET Core.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the detailed reply. Help me to understand things. My problem is solved, actually, the problem is in "appsetting.Json" file, while debugging, I use Immediate Window to check each and everything and found the value passed by (dependency injection) to connectionstrng(CS) is null and I start tracking the variables and file and found the connectionstrings section is in logging section that is why didn't get value and throwing that exception.

Once again thanks for your reply